# combineReducer and shape of the state

Tags: redux

In ["Basic Reducer Structure" in Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BasicReducerStructure.html), It is stated that:

> A typical app's state shape might look roughly like:

```
{
    domainData1 : {},
    domainData2 : {},
    appState1 : {},
    appState2 : {},
    ui : {
        uiState1 : {},
        uiState2 : {},
    }
}
```

Or

```
 { 
    simpleDomainData1: {....}, 
    simpleDomainData2: {....}, 
    entities : { 
        entityType1 : {....}, 
        entityType2 : {....} 
    },
    ui : { 
        uiSection1 : {....}, 
        uiSection2 : {....}, 
    }
}
```

Now I use `combineReducers` and I need to know how can I achieve this structure
considering `combineReducers` behavior which is that a corresponding key is set in **state** object for each reducer that is passed to `combineReducers`.

Do I have to have a reducer created for domainData1, domainData2, appState1, appState2 and ui?
Or there is another way for defining the shape of state like this?
Is it possible to disable combineReducers's behavior of adding key for each reducer to state?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you'd like to do, more specifically? You can achieve this state object both with and without `combineReducers` so it's a little confusing what you're asking.

Comment: I want to structure my app's state like this:
{
simpleDomainData1: {....},
simpleDomainData2: {....}
entities : {
entityType1 : {....},
entityType2 : {....}
} u
i : {
uiSection1 : {....},
uiSection2 : {....}
}
}

Comment: Yeah but which of those are reducers? You can think of each reducer as being a state object, so `combineReducers` lets you combine those under a single name, which you can choose.

Answer (score 0):

> `combineReducers` takes an object full of slice reducer functions, and
> creates a function that outputs a corresponding state object with the
> same keys.

For [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) this is definition of combine reducer.

**Do I have to have a reducer created for domainData1, domainData2, appState1, appState2 and ui?**

Yes, define reducer for each one and combine the reducer for each of them.
Like :
{
domainData1: domainData1Reducer,
domainData2: domainData2Reducer,
appState1 : appState1Reducer,
appState2 : appState1Reducer,,
ui: uiReducer,

}

**Is it possible to disable combineReducers's behavior of adding key for each reducer to state**

No, with combine Reducer you can't. But you can write your implementation for this.

**Or there is another way for defining the shape of state like this**?
Yes, we can do this too in single Reducer also.If you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
// don't provide keys to reducers that don't supply them
const filterReducer = (reducer) => {
  let lastState = undefined;
  return (state, action) => {
    if (lastState === undefined || state == undefined) {
      lastState = reducer(state, action);
      return lastState;
    }
    var filteredState = {};
    Object.keys(lastState).forEach( (key) => {
      filteredState[key] = state[key];
    });
    var newState = reducer(filteredState, action);
    lastState = newState;
    return newState;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

First I created `simpleDomainData1`, `simpleDomainData2`, `entityType1` , `entityType2` , and `uiSection1` and `uiSection2` .

And then I Combined entityType1 and entityType2 like this:

```
const entities = combineReducers({
    entityType1,
    entityType2,
});

const ui = combineReducers({
  uiSection1,
  uiSection2,
})
```

or instead you can create your own combineReducers function and use that:

```
const entities = (state, action) => {
    entityType1: entityType1(state.entityType1),
    entityType2: entityType2(state.entityType2)
}

const ui = (state, action) => {
    uiSection1: uiSection1(state.uiSection1),
    uiSection2: uiSection2(state.uiSection2)
}
```

And after that:

```
const allReducers = combineReducers({
    simpleDomainData1,
    simpleDomainData2,
    entities,
    ui    
});
```

Now the state shape will look like this:

```
 { 
    simpleDomainData1: {....}, 
    simpleDomainData2: {....}, 
    entities : { 
        entityType1 : {....}, 
        entityType2 : {....} 
    },
    ui : { 
        uiSection1 : {....}, 
        uiSection2 : {....}, 
    }
}
```